# How to search an array for a value?

Tags: java, arrays

I cant get case 3 and 4 to work correctly. I don't have an error but correct information is not displaying. For case 3, it displays the last item in the array even if another is entered.4 is not displaying.

These are the directions
The Video class should also have a static method called listVideosStarring that finds all movies that have
a particular star in them. This method takes a parameter that is the star’s name, and loop through the array
of products and concatenate the names of all the videos in the array that have the specified star in them.
Beware that not all the elements of this array point to Video instances; therefore, you will need to make
sure that a reference points to a Video instance before attempting to obtain the star. Also, since the Products
array is of type Product, you will need to treat the element as if it points to a Video to obtain the star's
name (this requires typecasting). Also keep in mind that because the member variable may contain more
than one star, you cannot assume that it necessarily equals the string entered by the user; instead you need
to see if the user’s entry is contained somewhere within the star member variable’s value.

Video and Automobile are subclasses of Product and products is the array

```
public class ProductsApplication {
    public static void main (String [] args){
        menuChoice();}
    
    //method for menu choices
    public static void menuChoice (){
        boolean loopContinue = true; 
        while (loopContinue){             
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Choices are: ");
        System.out.println("(1) Read products file");
        System.out.println("(2) List products and show total inventory value");
        System.out.println("(3) Display information about a product");
        System.out.println("(4) List products with a given star");
        System.out.println("(5) Show graph of inventory values");
        System.out.println("(6) Quit");
        System.out.println("What is your choice? (1-6)");
        try {
            String selection = scan.nextLine();
            switch(selection)
            {
                case "1":
                    try{
                        //Create file
                        File inputFile = new File("C:/Users/Olivia/Desktop/CIS331/products.txt");
                        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputFile);
                        //read data from file
                        for (int i= 0; i< Product.MAXPRODUCTS; i++)
                        {
                        while(scanner.hasNext()){
                            String type = scanner.nextLine(); 
                            if (type.equals("PRODUCT")){
                                String pName= scanner.nextLine();
                                String pDescription = scanner.nextLine();
                                int pQuantity = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
                                double pPrice = Double.parseDouble(scanner.nextLine());
                                boolean add = Product.addProduct(pName, pDescription, pQuantity, pPrice);
                            }
                            if (type.equals("AUTOMOBILE")){
                                String pName= scanner.nextLine();
                                String pDescription = scanner.nextLine();
                                int pQuantity = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
                                double pPrice = Double.parseDouble(scanner.nextLine());
                                int y = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
                                String mm = scanner.nextLine();
                                boolean add = Automobile.addAutomobile(pName, pDescription, pQuantity, pPrice, y, mm);
                            }
                            if(type.equals("VIDEO")){
                                String pName= scanner.nextLine();
                                String pDescription = scanner.nextLine();
                                int pQuantity = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
                                double pPrice = Double.parseDouble(scanner.nextLine());
                                String genere = scanner.nextLine();
                                String rate = scanner.nextLine();
                                int time = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
                                String star = scanner.nextLine();
                                boolean add= Video.addVideo(pName, pDescription, pQuantity, pPrice, genere, rate, time, star);
                            }                        
                            
                        }
                        }
                        System.out.println("File read successfully");
                    }
                    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        System.out.println("Error reading" + e.toString());
                    }
                    break;
                case "2":
                    System.out.println("List of products:");
                    System.out.println(Product.listProducts());
                    break;
                case "3":
                    System.out.print("Enter the name of the product: ");
                    String findName = scan.nextLine();
                    int index = Product.findProduct(findName);
                    if (index >=0){
                        Product product = Product.getProduct(index);
                        System.out.println(product.prodInfo(true));}
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("Product was not found");
                    }
                    break;
                case "4":
                    System.out.println("Enter the name of the star to search: ");
                    String starName = scan.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Videos starring " + starName);
                    System.out.println(Video.listVideoStarring(starName));
                    break;
                case "5":
                    
                    break;
                case "6":
                    System.exit(0);
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("error please try again");
                    break;
            }
        }
public class Product {
    //instance member variables of the class
    String productName;
    private String productDescription;
    private int productQuantity;
    private double unitPrice;
    
    //static member variables
    protected static final int MAXPRODUCTS = 10;
    protected static Product [] products;
    protected static int totProducts =0;
    
    
    //default constructor
    public Product(){
        this.productName = "PRODUCT"; 
        this.productDescription = "DESCRIPTION";
        this.productQuantity = 0;
        this.unitPrice = 0.0 ;
    }
    //overloaded constructor
    public Product(String name, String description, int quantity, double price){
        setproductName(name);
        setproductDescription(description);
        setproductQuantity(quantity);
        setunitPrice(price);
    }
    
    //getters and setters for instance varibles
    public void setproductName(String name){
        String firstLetter = name.substring(0,1).toUpperCase();
        String nameCapitalized = firstLetter + name.substring(1). toLowerCase();
        this.productName = nameCapitalized;      
    }
    public String getproductName (){
        return productName;
    }
    
    public void setproductDescription( String description){
        this.productDescription = description;
    }
    public String getproductDescription(){
        return productDescription;
    }
    public void setproductQuantity(int quantity){
        if (quantity < 0){
            this.productQuantity = 0;
        }
        else {
        this.productQuantity = quantity;
        }
    }
    public int getproductQuantity(){
        return productQuantity;
    }
    public void setunitPrice (double price){
        if (price<0){
            this.unitPrice = 0.00;
        }
        else{
        this.unitPrice = price;}
    }
    public double getunitPrice(){
        return unitPrice;
    }
     
    //Methods
    
    //Method for product information of a product instance
    public String prodInfo(boolean booleanVariable){      
        if (booleanVariable){
            NumberFormat numberFormat=NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);
            return "Product Name: " + getproductName() + System.lineSeparator()
                    + "Product Description: " + getproductDescription() + System.lineSeparator()
                    + "Product Quantity: " + getproductQuantity() + System.lineSeparator()
                    + "Product Price: " + numberFormat.format(getunitPrice()) + System.lineSeparator()
                    + "Total value: " + numberFormat.format(totalValue());}
        else {          
            return getproductName();
        }
    }
    
    //Method that returns the total value of the product, quantity times price
    public double totalValue(){
        return (this.productQuantity * this.unitPrice);
    }
    /*Method that takes string parameters and tests to see if that parameters value
        is equal to the value of products name, returns boolean*/
    public boolean testsValue(String testString){
        return this.getproductName().equalsIgnoreCase(productName);  
    }
    //list names in the product array
    public static String listProducts(){
        StringBuilder s= new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder s2 = new StringBuilder();
        if(products!= null && totProducts>0){
            for(int i=0; i<totProducts; i++){
                s.append(products[i].toString());
                s.append(" ");
                s.append(products[i].productName+"\n");
            } 
        }
        else{
            s.append("No products available.");
        }
        return s.toString();
    }
    //find product in an array
    public static int findProduct (String findName){
        int index = -1;
        if(products!=null && totProducts>0){
            for( int i=0; i<totProducts; i++){
                if(products[i].testsValue(findName))
                {
                    index = i;
                }
                else {
                    index = -1;
                    return index;
                }
            }
        }
        return index;
    }
    
    //add product to array
    public static boolean addProduct(String pName, String pDescription, int pQuantity, double pPrice){
        if(totProducts== MAXPRODUCTS)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if(products == null){
            products= new Product[MAXPRODUCTS];
            }
                Product newProduct = new Product(pName, pDescription, pQuantity, pPrice);
                products[totProducts]= newProduct;
                totProducts++;
                return true;
            } 

   
    // calculate total value of inventory in stock
    public static double totInventoryValue(){
        double sum = 0;
        if (products != null && totProducts>0){
            for(int i=0; i<totProducts; i++){
                sum+= products[i].totalValue();
            }
        }
        return sum;
    }
    
    //get accessor method for obtaining particular product from the index
    public static Product getProduct(int index){
        Product product= null;
        if(products!= null && totProducts>0 && index>=0 && index<totProducts){
            product = products[index];
        }
        return product;
    }
    // method added
    public String toString(){
        return "Product";
    }

    
}
public class Video extends Product{
    //instance member variables
    private String movieType;
    private String rating;
    private int runningTime;
    private String actors;
    
    //default constructor
    public Video(){
        super();
        this.movieType = "comedy";
        this.rating ="Not Rated";
        this.runningTime = 0;
        this.actors ="Unknown";
    }
    
    //Overloaded constructor
    public Video(String productName, String productDescription, int productQuantity, double unitPrice,
            String movieType, String rating, int runningTime, String actors){
        super(productName, productDescription, productQuantity, unitPrice);
        setmovieType(movieType);
        setrating(rating);
        setrunningTime(runningTime);
        setactors(actors);
    }
    
    //setters and getters
    public void setmovieType(String movieType){
        if(movieType.equals("comedy") || movieType.equals("drama") || movieType.equals("action") 
                || movieType.equals("documentary")){
            this.movieType = movieType;
        }
        else{
            this.movieType = "comedy";
        }
    }
    public String getmovieType(){
        return movieType;
    }
    public void setrating(String rating){
        if( rating.equals("G") || rating.equals("PG") || rating.equals("PG-13") || rating.equals("R")
                || rating.equals("Not Rated")){
            this.rating = rating;
        }
        else{
            this.rating = "Not Rated";
        }
    }
    public String getrating(){
        return rating;
    }
    public void setrunningTime(int runningTime){
        if (runningTime < 30){
            this.runningTime = 30;
        }
        if (runningTime > 500){
            this.runningTime = 500;
        }
        else{
            this.runningTime = runningTime;
        }        
    }
    public int getrunningTime(){
        return runningTime;
    }
    public void setactors(String actors){
        this.actors = actors;
    }
    public String getactors(){
        return actors;
    }
    // to string that overrides product class
    public String toString(){
        return "Video";
    }
    // add video, creating instance
    public static boolean addVideo(String productName, String productDescription, int productQuantity, double unitPrice,
            String movieType, String rating, int runningTime, String star){
        if(totProducts == MAXPRODUCTS)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (products == null){
            products= new Product[MAXPRODUCTS];
            }
                Video newVideo = new Video(productName, productDescription, productQuantity, unitPrice, movieType, rating,
                runningTime, star);
                Product.products[Product.totProducts]= newVideo;
                Product.totProducts++;
                return true;
    }
    
    //override prod info
    public String prodInfo(boolean booleanVariable){      
        if (booleanVariable){
            NumberFormat numberFormat=NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);
            return "Product Name: " + getproductName() + System.lineSeparator()
                    + "Product Description: " + getproductDescription() + System.lineSeparator()
                    + "Product Quantity: " + getproductQuantity() + System.lineSeparator()
                    + "Product Price: " + numberFormat.format(getunitPrice()) + System.lineSeparator()
                    + "Total value: " + numberFormat.format(totalValue()) + System.lineSeparator() + "Movie Type: " + getmovieType() + System.lineSeparator() 
                    + "Running Time: " + getrunningTime() + System.lineSeparator() + "Rating: " + getrating() + System.lineSeparator()
                    + "Stars: " + getactors() ;}
        else {          
            return getproductName();
        }
    }
    //new method to find movies that a star is in a movie
    public static String listVideoStarring(String starName){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i= 0; i<totProducts; i++){
            if (((Video)products[i]).contains(starName)){
                    sb.append(((Video)products[i]).productName.toString());
                }
            }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}

`
This is the text file I read in 
PRODUCT
Generic product
This is the description for product 1.
15000
12.50
VIDEO
Shrek
Animated movie about an ogre, a princess, and a donkey.
25000
15.25
comedy
PG
120
Mike Myers, Eddie Murphy, Cameron Diaz
AUTOMOBILE
Fancy car
A very cool and fast red sports car.
12
33999.99
2020
Ford Mustang
VIDEO
Goldmember
Hijinks of a British spy.
13000
8.45
comedy
PG-13
90
Mike Myers, Mindy Sterling, Michael Caine, Seth Greene, Heather Graham
AUTOMOBILE
Eco-friendly car
Better for the environment.
18
27999.99
2020
Toyota Prius
VIDEO
Black Panther
A Marvel Comics superhero movie
14000
13.75
drama
PG-13
90
Chadwick Boseman, Lupita Nyong'o, Michael B. Jordan
```

Comment: Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I do not know what the level of your class is; for instance, I don't know if you have worked with a debugger, or even whether you know what one is. It is the perfect tool for figuring out this kind of coding problem.

Comment: I have been trying to figure it out with the debugger, but I am not having any luck.

Comment: For 3, you should be able to use the debugger to see whether either the index that findProduct is returning is wrong, or the index is correct, but getProduct is returning the wrong Product instance.

Comment: @sorifiend they are already there, but I think we need all the Product classes too

Comment: I added the Product class and Video class to the code. Also added the text that case 1 reads in. Thanks.

Comment: What is `contains` in the line `if (((Video)products[i]).contains(starName)){`?

Comment: I was trying to find which movies contain a specific stars name, I guess that doesn't work. should I try equals?

Comment: Does that line currently compile?

Comment: I just looked at it again and it does not. I tried equals, but that still doe not do what I am trying to do. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: In the `Video` class, perhaps change: `if (((Video)products[i]).contains(starName)){` to this: `if (((Video)products[i]).actors.contains(starName)){`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, class `Product` should be abstract. You can't really create a "product" but you can create a *video* and you can create an *automobile*. However, from your code it appears that you can create a "generic" `Product` so in your circumstances, class `Product` should not be made abstract.

Default constructors don't make sense because a `productName` should be used to identify a `Product` object and therefore each `Product` object should have a unique `productName`. I would remove the default constructors.

Your identifiers do not strictly adhere to [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html). In the below code I have made the relevant changes.

In method `findProduct()`, of class `Product`, remove the `else`. You are only testing the first element in the array `products`. I assume that each `Product` must have a unique `productName` and therefore the method should be:

```java
public static int findProduct(String findName) {
    int index = -1;
    if (products != null && totProducts > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < totProducts; i++) {
            if (products[i].testsValue(findName)) {
                index = i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return index;
}
```

You should add another `addProduct()` [static] method to class `Product` with a single `Product` argument. Then you can add `Video` objects and `Automobile` objects to `products` array.

```java
public static boolean addProduct(Product newProduct) {
    if (products == null) {
        products = new Product[MAXPRODUCTS];
        totProducts = 0;
    }
    boolean added = false;
    if (newProduct != null  &&  totProducts < MAXPRODUCTS) {
        products[totProducts] = newProduct;
        totProducts++;
        added = true;
    }
    return added;
}
```

Consequently, you can change your existing `addProduct()` method.

```java
public static boolean addProduct(String pName,
                                 String pDescription,
                                 int    pQuantity,
                                 double pPrice) {
    return addProduct(new Product(pName, pDescription, pQuantity, pPrice));
}
```

When reading the `products.txt` file, you should use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to make sure that the file gets closed. Also, the `for` loop is not required. You should change the `while` loop so that it stops reading the file after `totProducts` equals `MAXPRODUCTS`.

You should almost always print the stack trace of exceptions rather than just print the error message as this will help you to locate the code that is causing the error.

Method `testsValue()`, in class `Product` is also wrong. You should check the parameter value.

```java
public boolean testsValue(String testString) {
    return this.getProductName().equalsIgnoreCase(testString);
}
```

Finally, you need to change method `listVideoStarring()`, in class `Video`.

```java
public static String listVideoStarring(String starName) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < totProducts; i++) {
        if (products[i] instanceof Video) {
            Video video = (Video) products[i];
            if (video.getActors().contains(starName)) {
                if (sb.length() > 0) {
                    sb.append(", ");
                }
                sb.append(video.getProductName());
            }
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Here is complete code.

Class `Video`

```java
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Video extends Product {
    // instance member variables
    private String movieType;
    private String rating;
    private int runningTime;
    private String actors;

    // Overloaded constructor
    public Video(String productName,
                 String productDescription,
                 int    productQuantity,
                 double unitPrice,
                 String movieType,
                 String rating,
                 int    runningTime,
                 String actors) {
        super(productName, productDescription, productQuantity, unitPrice);
        setMovieType(movieType);
        setRating(rating);
        setRunningTime(runningTime);
        setActors(actors);
    }

    // setters and getters
    public void setMovieType(String movieType) {
        if (movieType.equals("comedy") || movieType.equals("drama") || movieType.equals("action")
                || movieType.equals("documentary")) {
            this.movieType = movieType;
        }
        else {
            this.movieType = "comedy";
        }
    }

    public String getMovieType() {
        return movieType;
    }

    public void setRating(String rating) {
        if (rating.equals("G") || rating.equals("PG") || rating.equals("PG-13")
                || rating.equals("R") || rating.equals("Not Rated")) {
            this.rating = rating;
        }
        else {
            this.rating = "Not Rated";
        }
    }

    public String getRating() {
        return rating;
    }

    public void setRunningTime(int runningTime) {
        if (runningTime < 30) {
            this.runningTime = 30;
        }
        if (runningTime > 500) {
            this.runningTime = 500;
        }
        else {
            this.runningTime = runningTime;
        }
    }

    public int getRunningTime() {
        return runningTime;
    }

    public void setActors(String actors) {
        this.actors = actors;
    }

    public String getActors() {
        return actors;
    }

    // to string that overrides product class
    public String toString() {
        return "Video";
    }

    // add video, creating instance
    public static boolean addVideo(String productName, String productDescription,
            int productQuantity, double unitPrice, String movieType, String rating, int runningTime,
            String star) {
        if (totProducts == MAXPRODUCTS) {
            return false;
        }
        if (products == null) {
            products = new Product[MAXPRODUCTS];
        }
        Video newVideo = new Video(productName, productDescription, productQuantity, unitPrice,
                movieType, rating, runningTime, star);
        Product.products[Product.totProducts] = newVideo;
        Product.totProducts++;
        return true;
    }

    // override prod info
    public String prodInfo(boolean booleanVariable) {
        if (booleanVariable) {
            NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);
            return "Product Name: " + getProductName() + System.lineSeparator()
                    + "Product Description: " + getProductDescription() + System.lineSeparator()
                    + "Product Quantity: " + getProductQuantity() + System.lineSeparator()
                    + "Product Price: " + numberFormat.format(getUnitPrice())
                    + System.lineSeparator() + "Total value: " + numberFormat.format(totalValue())
                    + System.lineSeparator() + "Movie Type: " + getMovieType()
                    + System.lineSeparator() + "Running Time: " + getRunningTime()
                    + System.lineSeparator() + "Rating: " + getRating() + System.lineSeparator()
                    + "Stars: " + getActors();
        }
        else {
            return getProductName();
        }
    }

    // new method to find movies that a star is in a movie
    public static String listVideoStarring(String starName) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < totProducts; i++) {
            if (products[i] instanceof Video) {
                Video video = (Video) products[i];
                if (video.getActors().contains(starName)) {
                    if (sb.length() > 0) {
                        sb.append(", ");
                    }
                    sb.append(video.getProductName());
                }
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

---

Class `Product`

```java
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Product {
    // instance member variables of the class
    String productName;
    private String productDescription;
    private int productQuantity;
    private double unitPrice;

    // static member variables
    protected static final int MAXPRODUCTS = 10;
    protected static Product[] products;
    protected static int totProducts = 0;

    // overloaded constructor
    public Product(String name, String description, int quantity, double price) {
        setProductName(name);
        setProductDescription(description);
        setProductQuantity(quantity);
        setUnitPrice(price);
    }

    // getters and setters for instance varibles
    public void setProductName(String name) {
        String firstLetter = name.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();
        String nameCapitalized = firstLetter + name.substring(1).toLowerCase();
        this.productName = nameCapitalized;
    }

    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }

    public void setProductDescription(String description) {
        this.productDescription = description;
    }

    public String getProductDescription() {
        return productDescription;
    }

    public void setProductQuantity(int quantity) {
        if (quantity < 0) {
            this.productQuantity = 0;
        }
        else {
            this.productQuantity = quantity;
        }
    }

    public int getProductQuantity() {
        return productQuantity;
    }

    public void setUnitPrice(double price) {
        if (price < 0) {
            this.unitPrice = 0.00;
        }
        else {
            this.unitPrice = price;
        }
    }

    public double getUnitPrice() {
        return unitPrice;
    }

    // Methods

    // Method for product information of a product instance
    public String prodInfo(boolean booleanVariable) {
        if (booleanVariable) {
            NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);
            return "Product Name: " + getProductName() + System.lineSeparator()
                    + "Product Description: " + getProductDescription() + System.lineSeparator()
                    + "Product Quantity: " + getProductQuantity() + System.lineSeparator()
                    + "Product Price: " + numberFormat.format(getUnitPrice())
                    + System.lineSeparator() + "Total value: " + numberFormat.format(totalValue());
        }
        else {
            return getProductName();
        }
    }

    // Method that returns the total value of the product, quantity times price
    public double totalValue() {
        return (this.productQuantity * this.unitPrice);
    }

    /*
     * Method that takes string parameters and tests to see if that parameters value
     * is equal to the value of products name, returns boolean
     */
    public boolean testsValue(String testString) {
        return this.getProductName().equalsIgnoreCase(testString);
    }

    // list names in the product array
    public static String listProducts() {
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        if (products != null && totProducts > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < totProducts; i++) {
                s.append(products[i].toString());
                s.append(" ");
                s.append(products[i].productName + "\n");
            }
        }
        else {
            s.append("No products available.");
        }
        return s.toString();
    }

    // find product in an array
    public static int findProduct(String findName) {
        int index = -1;
        if (products != null && totProducts > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < totProducts; i++) {
                if (products[i].testsValue(findName)) {
                    index = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return index;
    }

    // add product to array
    public static boolean addProduct(String pName,
                                     String pDescription,
                                     int    pQuantity,
                                     double pPrice) {
        return addProduct(new Product(pName, pDescription, pQuantity, pPrice));
    }

    public static boolean addProduct(Product newProduct) {
        if (products == null) {
            products = new Product[MAXPRODUCTS];
            totProducts = 0;
        }
        boolean added = false;
        if (newProduct != null  &&  totProducts < MAXPRODUCTS) {
            products[totProducts] = newProduct;
            totProducts++;
            added = true;
        }
        return added;
    }

    // calculate total value of inventory in stock
    public static double totInventoryValue() {
        double sum = 0;
        if (products != null && totProducts > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < totProducts; i++) {
                sum += products[i].totalValue();
            }
        }
        return sum;
    }

    // get accessor method for obtaining particular product from the index
    public static Product getProduct(int index) {
        Product product = null;
        if (products != null && totProducts > 0 && index >= 0 && index < totProducts) {
            product = products[index];
        }
        return product;
    }

    // method added
    public String toString() {
        return "Product";
    }
}
```

---

Class `ProductsApplication`

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ProductsApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        menuChoice();
    }

    // method for menu choices
    public static void menuChoice() {
        boolean loopContinue = true;
        while (loopContinue) {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Choices are: ");
            System.out.println("(1) Read products file");
            System.out.println("(2) List products and show total inventory value");
            System.out.println("(3) Display information about a product");
            System.out.println("(4) List products with a given star");
            System.out.println("(5) Show graph of inventory values");
            System.out.println("(6) Quit");
            System.out.println("What is your choice? (1-6)");
            try {
                String selection = scan.nextLine();
                switch (selection) {
                    case "1":
                        // Create file
                        File inputFile = new File("C:/Users/Olivia/Desktop/CIS331products.txt");
                        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputFile)) {
                            // read data from file
                            while (scanner.hasNextLine()
                                    && Product.totProducts < Product.MAXPRODUCTS) {
                                String type = scanner.nextLine();
                                if (type.equals("PRODUCT")) {
                                    String pName = scanner.nextLine();
                                    String pDescription = scanner.nextLine();
                                    int pQuantity = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
                                    double pPrice = Double.parseDouble(scanner.nextLine());
                                    boolean add = Product.addProduct(pName,
                                                                     pDescription,
                                                                     pQuantity,
                                                                     pPrice);
                                }
                                if (type.equals("AUTOMOBILE")) {
                                    String pName = scanner.nextLine();
                                    String pDescription = scanner.nextLine();
                                    int pQuantity = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
                                    double pPrice = Double.parseDouble(scanner.nextLine());
                                    int y = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
                                    String mm = scanner.nextLine();
                                    boolean add = Product.addProduct(new Automobile(pName,
                                                                                    pDescription,
                                                                                    pQuantity,
                                                                                    pPrice,
                                                                                    y,
                                                                                    mm));
                                }
                                if (type.equals("VIDEO")) {
                                    String pName = scanner.nextLine();
                                    String pDescription = scanner.nextLine();
                                    int pQuantity = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
                                    double pPrice = Double.parseDouble(scanner.nextLine());
                                    String genere = scanner.nextLine();
                                    String rate = scanner.nextLine();
                                    int time = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
                                    String star = scanner.nextLine();
                                    boolean add = Product.addProduct(new Video(pName,
                                                                               pDescription,
                                                                               pQuantity,
                                                                               pPrice,
                                                                               genere,
                                                                               rate,
                                                                               time,
                                                                               star));
                                }
                            }
                            System.out.println("File read successfully");
                        }
                        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        break;
                    case "2":
                        System.out.println("List of products:");
                        System.out.println(Product.listProducts());
                        break;
                    case "3":
                        System.out.print("Enter the name of the product: ");
                        String findName = scan.nextLine();
                        int index = Product.findProduct(findName);
                        if (index >= 0) {
                            Product product = Product.getProduct(index);
                            System.out.println(product.prodInfo(true));
                        }
                        else {
                            System.out.println("Product was not found");
                        }
                        break;
                    case "4":
                        System.out.println("Enter the name of the star to search: ");
                        String starName = scan.nextLine();
                        System.out.println("Videos starring " + starName);
                        System.out.println(Video.listVideoStarring(starName));
                        break;
                    case "5":
                        break;
                    case "6":
                        System.exit(0);
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("error please try again");
                        break;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception x) {
                x.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```